# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Change Tracking, Database Snapshots, invalid rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a system in place where a SQL Server 2008 R2 database is being mirrored to a second server.  The database on the first server has change tracking turned on and on the second server we create a database snapshot of the mirror database in order to pull data for an ETL system with the change tracking functions.  Both databases have an isolation level of Read Committed

Occasionally when we pull the change tracking information from the database snapshot,using the changetable function, there is a row that is either an insert or update (i,u) but the row is not in the base table, it is deleted.  When I go to check the first server, the changetable function shows only a 'd' row for the same primary key.  It appears that the snapshot was taken right at the time the delete happened on the base table but before the information was tracked by change tracking.

**My questions are:**

- Is the mechanism for capturing change tracking in the change tracking internal tables asynchronous?
  EDIT:
  The mechanism for change tracking is synchronous and a part of the transaction making the change to the table.  I found that information here:
  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.11.sql.aspx

So that leaves me with these questions.

- Why am I seeing the behavior I outlined above?  If change tracking is synchronous why would I get inserts/updates from change tracking that don't have a corresponding row in the table?
- Would changing the isolation level to snapshot isolation help alleviate the above situation?
  EDIT:
  After reading more about snapshot isolation recommendation it is recommended so that you can wrap your call to change_tracking_current_version and the call to changetable(changes...) in a transaction so that everything stays consistent.  The database snapshot should be doing that for me since it is as of a point in time.  I pass in the value from change_tracking_current_version into changetable(changes...) function.

Let me know if you need any more information!

Thanks

Chris